# list s3 object permissions via SDK / CLI / API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to check which objects in the bucket are public available.
I can run `$s3->listObjectsV2` successfully, but I do not see any permissions here at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'd like to be able to change the permissions for files and folders without re-uploading them. How can I do it?

NOTE: it doesn't really matter for me what to use: SDK / CLI / API, however  CLI or PHP SDK perferable.

Comment: There is no such command for S3 that will list the permissions on a S3 Object

Comment: @error2007s Any way except web console?

Comment: Yes you can just get that from AWS web console. Check the usage of listobjectv2 here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html